# Highcharts custom datetime axis

Tags: highcharts, axis

I want to make a timeline graph that is cut into 3 parts, all 3 parts should have the same width
part 1: 1 month
part 2: 1 week
part 3: 1 day (today till current time)

now i have been looking at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

I think this should be solvable with tickPositioner and adding units.
But truth be told, my javascript knowledge fails me here.

```
 tickPositioner: function () {
    var positions = [],
    tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
    increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);
}
```

Comment: So you need to have 3 ticks, and each should have differenet label (month/week/day) ?

Comment: Yes that is the idea, also the 3 ticks should be the same size(width)

Comment: Maybe using [categories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories) will be fine?

Comment: Hmm that might work, i could try that. Thanks